# CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL returns NULL

Tags: objective-c, cgimagesource

I want to get the Size of the image without loading it so i am using the below code

```
-(float)gettingimagedimensions:(NSString*)url{
    NSURL *imageFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:url];
    //CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageFileURL, NULL);
    CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)imageFileURL, NULL);
    if (imageSource == NULL) {
        // Error loading image

        return 0;
    }

    CGFloat width = 0.0f, height = 0.0f;
    CFDictionaryRef imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, NULL);
    if (imageProperties != NULL) {
        CFNumberRef widthNum  = CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth);
        if (widthNum != NULL) {
            CFNumberGetValue(widthNum, kCFNumberFloatType, &width);
        }

        CFNumberRef heightNum = CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight);
        if (heightNum != NULL) {
            CFNumberGetValue(heightNum, kCFNumberFloatType, &height);
        }

        CFRelease(imageProperties);
    }

    NSLog(@"Image dimensions: %.0f x %.0f px", width, height);

    return height;
}
```

The Problem is that imageSource is always NULL 
Does any body has any idea , why it is not working !!

Please Note that URL are Valid links to images JPG or PNG

Comment: if you got answer for this question then please let me know. I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have ARC enabled?  I don't and my working code is as follows:

```
NSURL * imageFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fp];
CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)imageFileURL, NULL);
```

Note the absence of `__bridge`.  I call `CFRelease` on `imageSource` when done btw.